# How to publish messages on a topic of type rosgraph_msgs/Clock?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, roscpp, clock

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I want to give values to a topic with this type of mesage (rosgraph_msgs/Clock)

I create a variable called "reloj" for example:

rosgraph_msgs::Clock reloj;

How do I give a value to that variable?, because it has two parts (secs and nsecs)

For example in float64 I give it the value this way

std_msgs::Float64 variable;

variable.data = 0;

I would like to do the same but in rosgraph_msgs/Clock, one value for "secs" and one for "nsecs"

I tried: reloj.clock.secs = 1;   reloj.clock.nsecs = 100;

reloj.clock_secs = 1; reloj.clock_nsecs = 100;

But this does not work

I found that putting the following does work

reloj.clock = {5,88};

but when creating the node executable, I get this warning:

warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
reloj.clock = {5,88};

I use ROS kinetic and roscpp (c++)

this is the code in c++

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "rosgraph_msgs/Clock.h"
rosgraph_msgs::Clock reloj;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "pubsubclock");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Publisher publicador;
publicador  = n.advertise<rosgraph_msgs::Clock>("topico_pub", 1000);
reloj.clock = {5,88};
ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
while (ros::ok()) {
publicador.publish(reloj);
ros::spinOnce();
loop_rate.sleep();
}  
return 0;
}
```

thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260106/how-to-publish-messages-on-a-topic-of-type-rosgraph_msgs/clock?/) by [manupe94](https://answers.ros.org/users/30136/manupe94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-04-24**:\

> But this does not work

that doesn't tell us very much. Please explain what you found that "does not work". Include any error messages that you get.

Please use the `edit` button/link to update your original question.

**Comment by [manupe94](https://answers.ros.org/users/30136/manupe94/) on 2017-04-24**:
I updated the message

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-24**:
The syntax `reloj.clock = {5,88};` is a form of constructor calling that is new in C++11. You cannot use it without telling the compiler to compile in C++11 mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `rosgraph_msgs::Clock` message definition field `clock` has the msg data type `time`. In C++ this maps to the [`ros::Time` class](http://docs.ros.org/api/rostime/html/classros_1_1Time.html). You need to use that class to work with it. For example:

```
reloj.clock = ros::Time(1, 100);
```

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Craigstar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20181/craigstar/) on 2020-03-27**:
I'm attempting to do something similar from Python, and managed to determine that rosgraph_msgs/Clock was using the field clock of type time.  But trying to jam a Time into a type rosgraph_msgs/Clock does not appear to work.

**Comment by [Craigstar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20181/craigstar/) on 2020-03-27**:
code sample follows...

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Time
from rosgraph_msgs.msg import Clock

def simtime_talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('timey',Time, queue_size=10)
    pub1 = rospy.Publisher('clockey',Clock, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
    sim_speed_multiplier = 10
    
    zero_time = rospy.get_time()
    
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        
        timepassed_dat = rospy.get_time() - zero_time
        timepassedaccelerated_dat = sim_speed_multiplier*timepassed_dat
        time_dat = rospy.Time.from_sec(timepassedaccelerated_dat)
        
        pub.publish(rospy.get_time())
        pub1.publish(time_dat)
        rate.sleep(
```